# How to detect end of elements in div with jQuery each() on multiple div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, each

I have several divs that have the same class `.timeline-travel-steps`. These divs contain elements `.step` that I want to select with `jQuery each()` Method

**HTML**

```
<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>

<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
var i = 0;
$(".timeline-graphic .step").each(function(index, value) {
  $(this).css('left', i + 'px');
  i = i + 20;
});
```

It works but I need to know when the `each()` reaches the end of a div `timeline-travel-steps`. Currently the `each()` continues and run the elements contained in the other divs. It would be very simple if each divs had a different and static class but these divs are generated by a cms and I don't know how many there are.

I need something like :

```
if (isLastElement) {
    i = 0;
}
```

I've tried to play with `index` and `.length` but the `each()` continues to run.

Here is a snippet

```js
var i = 0;
$(".timeline-graphic .step").each(function(index, value) {
  //console.log(index);
  var numItems = $(this).parent().length;
  console.log(numItems);
  $(this).css('left', i + 'px');
  i = i + 20;
});
```

```css
.timeline-graphic {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0 auto 80px auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.step {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>

<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use each along with the `index` argument there is no need to use another counter variable. Just cycle all `.step` elements for each `.timeline-graphic` element

```
$('.timeline-graphic').each(function() {
  $('.step', this).each(function(index, v) {
     console.log(index);
     $(this).css('left', (index * 20) + 'px');
  });
})
```

As a side note there is no even need to use `jQuery` and/or `position: absolute` for this kind of task when you can use use only `CSS`, by adjusting the distance of the dots inside a `Flexbox` container  with the `gap` property:

```css
.timeline-graphic {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 2rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
              transparent 0,
              transparent calc(50% - 2px),
              
              #000 0,
              #000 calc(50% + 2px),
              transparent 0
  ) repeat-x;
}


.step {
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   aspect-ratio: 1;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>

<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>
```

In case the distance of the dots were determined by JavaScript, you could still go with the CSS solution and use JS to just update a custom variable, e.g.

```css
:root {
  --gap: 0;
}

.timeline-graphic {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: var(--gap);
  height: 2rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
              transparent 0,
              transparent calc(50% - 2px),
              
              #000 0,
              #000 calc(50% + 2px),
              transparent 0
  ) repeat-x;
}


.step {
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   aspect-ratio: 1;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="gap" id="gap-label">Adjust the gap via JS</label>
<input type="range" id="gap" 
       aria-labelledby="gap-label"
       min="0" max="40" step="1" value="0"
       oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--gap', this.value + 'px');" />


<hr />

<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>

<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, I have already done nested `each()` but I did not think about it in this case. The CSS solution is more elegant and modern. I will use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the current `step` is the last in the parent by using

```
$(this).is(":last-child")
```

Note: it does need to be the last element, not just the last `step` (without elements after).   Nested `each` is the cleanest solution (IMO) - see other answer.

There's an [experimental](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_nth-last-child_of_syntax) `:nth-last-child(1 of .step)` but that only works in Safari (so not recommended)

Updated snippet (without making any other changes, so this is unlikely to be the optimal/final solution)

```js
var i = 0;
$(".timeline-graphic .step").each(function(index, value) {
  var numItems = $(this).parent().length;
  $(this).css('left', i + 'px');
  i = i + 20;
  if ($(this).is(":last-child")) i = 0;
});
```

```css
.timeline-graphic {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0 auto 80px auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.step {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>

<div class="timeline-graphic">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>
```